# How to get coefficients at once using lbreg in a simulation study

Tags: r, simulation

I have 1000 datasets which I have run an analysis using the logbinomial package(lbreg) but my results are in a list and I am trying to convert it into a data frame. I have a code and will provide how the list is like because the list has 23 elements for each output for the 1000 datasets

I have tried a lot of things but not converting so I have figured out how the coefficients are packed but now I need to get them once instead of doing 1000 times

```
library(lbreg)
nsim = 1000
for(k in 1:nsim){
  dat <- mydata1[mydata1$Sim == k,]
  sp <- split(mydata1, mydata1$Sim)
  model_list <- lapply(sp, function(dat){
    tryCatch(model1 <- lbreg(y ~ x1+x2, family = binomial(link = log), data = dat),
             error = function(e) e)
  })
}
ok <- !sapply(model_list, inherits, 'error')
fitlist <- model_list[ok]
```

I have tried using

```
data.frame(matrix(unlist(fitlist), nrow=1000, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

but it failed.

If I do this I get the coefficients but I have to do it up to 1000 to get all the coefficients

```
data.frame(coef(fitlist$`1`), coef(fitlist$`2`), coef(fitlist$`3`), coef(fitlist$`4`), coef(fitlist$`4`), coef(fitlist$`5`))
```

For a dataset, if you want to check it out 
https://github.com/Seanlove89/logitdata

Comment: I am not sure if someone can help me on the efficiency of the code above. It is taking too long and I have to force it to stop but it will already have solutions in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Using base R
do.call("rbind",lapply(fitlist, function(x) data.frame(t(coef(x)))))
#or using `purrr`
purrr::map_df(set_names(fitlist, nm=1:length(lstfit)), 
              ~data.frame(t(coef(.x))), 
             .id = "model")
```

Comment: Thanks so much the code works well. I used the first one